# Sitecore Express Migration Tool 3.0 - Error on run

Tags: migration, sitecore, sitecore8

I am trying to migrate a Sitecore 8.0 installation to Sitecore 9.0, and the documentation in the Sitecore Developer portal suggests using the Sitecore Express Migration Tool as the most painless way to do this. However, when I run the application I get an immediate error:

[An unexpected error has occured. Please restart the tool and try again. For more information, see the log files.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iMJE.png)

I checked the log files and I only see this:

```
[  1] 11:40:43.421 INFO  [WizardCore] Moving to the next step. Current step key: ''.
[  1] 11:40:43.510 ERROR Unable to perform wizard step transition. Source: <no>, Target: basic_parameters_step.
System.NotSupportedException: An attempt was made to load an assembly from a network location which would have caused the assembly to be sandboxed in previous versions of the .NET Framework. This release of the .NET Framework does not enable CAS policy by default, so this load may be dangerous. If this load is not intended to sandbox the assembly, please enable the loadFromRemoteSources switch. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569 for more information.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoadFile(String path, Evidence evidence)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(String path)
   at Sitecore.ExpressMigration.Core.Plugin.PluginRepository.LoadPlugins() in C:\BA\e849cf469cb4cf58\src\Sitecore.ExpressMigration.Core\Plugin\PluginRepository.cs:line 44
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at Sitecore.ExpressMigration.Pipelines.WizardSteps.CreateBasicParameters.AddModuleVersionSelectors.Process(CreateBasicParametersArgs args) in C:\BA\e849cf469cb4cf58\src\Sitecore.ExpressMigration\Pipelines\WizardSteps\CreateBasicParameters\30_AddModuleVersionSelectors.cs:line 54
   at Sitecore.ExpressMigration.Core.Pipelines.PipelinesService.Pipeline.Run[T](T args) in C:\BA\e849cf469cb4cf58\src\Sitecore.ExpressMigration.Core\Pipelines\PipelinesService\Pipeline.cs:line 54
   at Sitecore.ExpressMigration.Wizard.Steps.Start.BasicParameters.BasicParametersStep.CreateRootDataRequest(Migration migration) in C:\BA\e849cf469cb4cf58\src\Sitecore.ExpressMigration\Wizard\Steps\Start\BasicParameters\BasicParametersStep.cs:line 119
   at Sitecore.ExpressMigration.Wizard.Steps.Start.BasicParameters.BasicParametersStep.<OnBeforeStepEnterAsync>d__29.MoveNext() in C:\BA\e849cf469cb4cf58\src\Sitecore.ExpressMigration\Wizard\Steps\Start\BasicParameters\BasicParametersStep.cs:line 84
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.ExpressMigration.Wizard.Core.WizardCore.<PerformStepTransitionAsync>d__51.MoveNext() in C:\BA\e849cf469cb4cf58\src\Sitecore.ExpressMigration\Wizard\Core\WizardCore.cs:line 220
[  1] 11:41:06.247 INFO  [WizardCore] Moved to the next step. Current step key: ''.
```

This is default, without any configuration changes; the system paths referenced do not exist on my system (C:\BA\e849cf469cb4cf58) and I'm not sure how to specify where my actual Sitecore project folder is. I've been looking through the migration document on the Developer portal, but everything documented is written assuming starting the application worked.

What can I do to get past this error? Is there some configuration changes I need to make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open Sitecore.ExpressMigration.exe.config
2. Add the following line `<loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" />` to the `<runtime>` section

Comment: This is the same fix for 2.0 of the tool as well.